# iPhone 6 was stolen

Tags: ios, find-my-iphone

My iPhone 6 was stolen.
Used find my iPhone app and put it into lost mode on my iPad. Got a text from Find my iPhone app stating it was located. But now I don't see it in the find my iPhone app anymore?
Did it get wiped, gone for good?

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: [Apple Find My iPhone Support Article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204233)

The article says that there are three possible reasons for your problem:

It's powered off, the battery has run out, or it’s been more than 24 hours since the last location was sent to Apple (if Send Last Location is turned on). When your device is connected to the Internet, you can see the remaining battery in the upper-right corner of the information pane. 
Your iPad, iPod Touch, or Mac is asleep and not connected to a known Wi-Fi or data network. Wait a few minutes and try again.
You're in a country where we don't offer this feature. This feature might not be available in your country due to technical limitations or local law.

Good luck!